# Как правильно найти DLL в GAC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com, gac

Проблема такая. Написал библиотеку типов на C#. Пока дебажил проблем не было, так как проект самой библиотеки входил в решения приложений и пересобирался вместе с ними. Но как только стало нужно изолировать приложения друг от друга, ожидаемо появились проблемы. Нужно сделать так, чтобы приложения видели мою библиотеку по имени, то есть чтобы не было обязательно ее присутствие в той же папке, где находится приложение.

Сначала пробовал зарегистрировать DLL для COM-взаимодействия, но для этого придется переписывать бОльшую часть кода библиотеки. Потом обратил внимание на вариант с GAC, но и тут не получилось, так как регистрация проходит, но я не вижу сборку в списке в Visual Studio. Внятного ответа на то, как включить библиотеку в этот список найти на просторах интернета не смог.

Регистрировал командой к приложению C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\gacutil.exe -i [Путь к приложению]. После утилита показывала мне, что библиотека действительно зарегистрирована, но в списке она не появлялась(

Как правильно добавить DLL в проект, если она самописная и зарегистрирована в GAC? Из разговора в комментах понял, что меня спасет только он (в смысле GAC).

Как делал я: прогнал команду в консоли способом, описанным выше, далее в проекте попытался добавить ссылку на нее, но библиотеки не нашел. Может я не там искал?

[image: Вот в этом списке я искал, "Платформа" и "Расширения". Окно открывается при нажатии "Добавить ссылку"]

UPD: После прочтения всех статей ни одна не помогла. Описываемых веток реестра не существует. Единственное, что работает, это поместить сборку по адресу C:\Windows\Assembly она становится видимой, но это не вариант.

Comment: почему бы не оформить ваш код Nuget пакетом?

Comment: а как это поможет? Цель в том, чтобы без перекомпиляции приложений, зависящих от библиотеки, обновлять ее функционал. Но может я что-то не понял...

Comment: а, если без перекомпиляции, то вам да, либо GAC, либо реализовать модульность (то есть возможноть грузить модули в приложение динамически)

Comment: ещё раз перечитал вопрос. вот с этим требованием - `то есть чтобы не было обязательно ее присутствие в той же папке, где находится приложение.` да, получается только GAC.

Comment: `но в списке она не появлялась` - в каком списке? в студии? Перегружали студию после регистрации?

Comment: Да, в студии в списке сборок (Платформа и Расширения). Может я неправильно ищу?

Comment: Студию перезапускали? Правильно ли вы ищете я не подскажу, у меня студия на английском и 15 версии

Comment: Перезапускал, конечно)

Comment: закиньте скриншот как вы ищете в вопрос, может вам ктото подскажет

Comment: А может кто-нибудь поделится ссылкой на правильную инструкцию? Или ее не существует

Comment: [Практическое руководство. Установка сборки в глобальный кэш сборок](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac) ,  [Практическое руководство. Добавление и удаление ссылок с помощью диспетчера ссылок](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019)

Comment: [Работа со сборками и глобальным кэшем сборок](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/app-domains/working-with-assemblies-and-the-gac)

Comment: А имя у сборки строгое? Там же, на сколько я помню, нужно их подписывать еще.

Comment: Да, имя строгое

Answer (score 0):

Правильный ответ - никак.
Так как при добавлении в GAC уже невозможно воспользоваться подсказками (читай - intellisence-ом), нужно добавлять функции на лету.
В моей ситуации есть 2 выхода. Первый - переписывать dll на com, и ссылаться на нее без копирования в директорию. Но не будет конструкторов и многого другого, плюс - все переписать. Второй - включать в проект приложения проект библиотеки и таскать ее вместе с собой, что неудобно в плане развертывания. Я выбрал второй вариант, так как переписывать все неохота.
Спасибо за отсутствие ответов и запихивание бесполезных ссылок на msdn.